# A F# example on book, but I can't even compile it

Tags: f#

I'm reading the book 'Beginning F#',
There's a short list for example code, to demonstrate the lazy evaluation as follows:

```
lazyValue = lazy ( 2 + 2 )
let actualValue = Lazy.force lazyValue
printfn "%i" actualValue
```

It seems easy, but there's a error to me, say that function force isn't defined???

I'm confused about that. Searching from the msdn, it seems no answer.

Anyone can tell me what happened??

Comment: The book was published before F# first shipped in VS2010, and some of the library API changed or was refactored in between.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For some reason, [Lazy.force](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/68767#685028) is in F# PowerPack now.

Since this function doesn't have dependency, I suggest you to copy it from [F# PowerPack](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) for convenient use:

```
module Lazy =
    let force (x: Lazy<'T>) = x.Force()
```

Comment: F# PowerPack is a collection of libraries and a compiler,it embeds into Visual Studio 2010？

Comment: It is a collection of libraries. You can download from the link I provided.

Answer (score 4):

The author wrote `Lazy.force` because the author probably used OCaml before. F# gravitated from OCaml style API to C# style API over time. Now people write `x.Value` or `x.Force()`. instead.

Answer (score 2):

You code should be

```
    let lazyValue = lazy ( 2 + 2 )
    let actualValue = lazyValue.Force()
    printfn "%i" actualValue
```

Comment: yes, i know this     let actualValue = lazyValue.Force() is ok ,but what's 'Lazy.force ' why the author wrote that code.